# What does (...) mean in a legal document

Tags: contract-law

What does the (...) mean in this section:

> (1) Mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu fünf Jahren oder mit Geldstrafe wird bestraft, wer
>
> (...)
>
> (3) Ebenso wird bestraft, wer etc.

If I saw this in a document I would assume that it means "ignore this irrelevant text to allow you to concentrate on the important text." Especially seeing as (2) appears to be missing in this case.

However, if that is the meaning of it, how can you possibly sign a document with parts of it missing?

Comment: Normally such ellipses occur when one document quotes another.  Is the material a quotation in this case?  It's difficult to suggest an interpretation without the context.

Comment: I noticed a declaration that indicates the meaning of it. It translates to `Text omissions (...) are to be made intentionally, since the omitted texts are irrelevant in the context of this declaration.`. I should have searched the document for it. It is strange that it would cut a sentence in half though... The document itself derives from: https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Formular/WA/fo_Art_18MAR_WA25_doc.doc?__blob=publicationFile&v=3

Comment: [Please do not use codeblocks for emphasis](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/3942/53718). Quoteblocks and emphasis should be used where necessary.

Comment: Sounds like problem solved with no need for a further answer.

Comment: Yes, solved enough. Should I delete this question, or answer it myself? I'm not sure this question would help a future reader.

Comment: @Knossos Answer it yourself. That way, if somebody else has this question and doesn't have a copy of Microsoft Word, they can find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a declaration that indicates the meaning of it.

It translates to "Text omissions (...) are to be made intentionally, since the omitted texts are irrelevant in the context of this declaration".

I should have searched the document for it. It is strange that it would cut a sentence in half though...

The document itself [derives from this source](https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Formular/WA/fo_Art_18MAR_WA25_doc.doc?__blob=publicationFile&v=3).